# Property with method?

Tags: c#, .net

Maybe I am overlooking something obvious, but I have seen in code where you may have a property like "HairColor", and then a method like "HairColor.Update()". Is this possible?

```
Person person = new Person(int personID);
person.HairColor = "Blonde";
person.HairColor.Update();
```

I have specific properties that I want to be able to extend on a case by case basis. I guess I could have a method called "HairColorUpdate", but seems that HairColor.Update() should be possible. I don't want to use "set" because I don't always want to update the DB this way.

The reason I am doing this is because I may only want to call the database to update one column instead of calling my save method which updates every column hopefully improving efficiency.

Comment: You're just making things more complicated by updating field for field. Provide a `Update` method in your Person class that updates all fields(use Parameters). There's almost no performance difference for the dbms.

Comment: If you want to update one column I would take a look at my answer.  The others are good solutions too, but its just how I would do it. B

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`person.HairColor.Update()` just means that the type returned by the `HairColor` property has a method called `Update`. In your example it looks like `HairColor` is a `string`, so to achieve that you need to implement an extension method for `string`. E.g. something like

```
static class StringExtension
{
    public static void Update(this string s)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

However, I don't see the point of doing this. The `Update` method is a static method that works on the string, so it doesn't affect the `Person` instance. (even if `string` did have an `Update` method it would be unrelated to the `Person` type).

I believe you would want to have the `Update` method on `Person` instead as others have pointed out.

Comment: +1 for just mentioning "I don't see the point of doing this."

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That's what I tried to cover with the not making much sense part.

Comment: The only downside here is that *every* string will now be `Update`-able. Guess you can cope for that by intelligent use of namespaces, though...

Comment: @code4life: I don't believe that is the only downside. This doesn't read like regular C# code to me. I believe the update method should be on the `Person` type.

Comment: That won't work for what I am trying to do, but I like your answer. I use extensions quite often, but I guess it's not a good fit for what I am trying to do. I currently have an update on the class, which just updates all fields. I only want to update one field at a time. So I will just have to write a method that checks which fields were updated, or just pass a field to update. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

That is not possible, unless the return value of HairColor has an Update() method. Another way to do this is to have

```
Person person = new Person(int personID);
person.HairColor = "Blonde";
person.Update();
```

Where the update method checks to see which fields have been updated and then updates the database based on that information.

Comment: I guess checking to see which properties were updated, and updating those only might make more sense. That's what I am trying to achieve essentially. I want to avoid updating the entire record when only one field needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

`HairColor` would probably have to be a struct type to make what you want to work. Plus, you would have to do operator overloading. I'm not sure if this is truly the design path you want to pursue. If, for some perverse reason, you **absolutely** must do it, this is the kind of struct definition you would need (very roughly, LOL):

```
public struct HairColorStruct
{
    private string m_hairColor;

    public void Update()
    {
        // do whatever you need to do here...
    }

    // the very basic operator overloads that you would need...
    public static implicit operator HairColorStruct(string color)
    {
        var result = new HairColorStruct();
        result.m_hairColor = color;
        return result;
    }

    public static explicit operator string(HairColorStruct hc)
    {
        return hc.m_hairColor;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return m_hairColor;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(HairColorStruct from, HairColorStruct to)
    {
        return from.m_hairColor == to.m_hairColor;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(HairColorStruct from, string to)
    {
        return from.m_hairColor == to;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(HairColorStruct from, HairColorStruct to)
    {
        return from.m_hairColor != to.m_hairColor;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(HairColorStruct from, string to)
    {
        return from.m_hairColor != to;
    }
}
```

You can then redefine your `Person` object like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public HairColorStruct HairColor { get; set; }

    // whatever else goes here...
}
```

In your code, `HairColor` can be simply assigned whatever you desire as long as it's a `string`:

```
var person = new Person();
person.HairColor = "Blonde";

// this will emit "True" to the console...
if (person.HairColor == "Blonde")
{
    Console.WriteLine(true);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(false);
}

// update the info per your logic...
person.HairColor.Update();

// you can change the hair color and update again, LOL
person.HairColor = "Brown";
person.HairColor.Update();
```

Comment: I was writing this up for the OP. Beat me to it. +1 on answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `property` with a method, but `type` returned by the property has that method declared inside. So you use a property and within returned value, which is the type, call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Update method on the Person class, not Update method on string:

```
Person person = new Person(int personID);
person.HairColor = "Blonde";
// set other properties
person.Update();
```

Actually mixing business logic of person class and database-related logic is rarely good idea. So, I'd go to something like:

```
dbSession.SaveOrUpdate(person); // NHibernate
```

Or even extension method:

```
public static void Update(this Person person)
{
   // connect to database and do update query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

```
public class HairColor : String
{
     private int _personID;

     public HairColor(int personID)
     {
         _personID = personID;
     }

     public void Update()
     {
          //update the database here for hair color
     }
}
```

This way you can have more control with specific functionality.  Remember, class responsibility.

This solution is only if you really want to update one column of course.

Hope that helps.