# methods of a property

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I have a class and inside I want to have two properties, and I want each property have their specific methods. for example I have a class named `myClass`, two properties `propA` and `propB`.
now I want that `propA` have two methods for example `getID()` and `getName()`
and same for `propB` with different methods.
accessing the specific method would be like `myClass.propA.getName();`
I created the property but I couldn't find how to assign the methods to that property
also I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915866/property-with-method) question but I didn't understand the answer correctly.
any help would be great.

Comment: its an `Extension Method`. You can create `Extension Method` for a particular type `string,int,class etc`.

Comment: Read some book about C#. And then implement your properties with type of classes containing needed methods.

Comment: What type of properties `propA` and `propB` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what complexity do you want. If your properties are of a simple type (like int, string, etc) then create extension methods (like from Ravi`s ansver). But more likely that your properties are more complex, so you could end up creating new classes for them, like:

```
class MyClass
{
   public A PropA { get; set; }
   public B PropB { get; set; }
}

class A
{
    public void Foo() { ... }
}

class B
{
    public void Bar() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using `Extension Methods`

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic,
>   there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method
>   and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

How to Use

```
string s = "Hello Extension Methods";
int i = s.WordCount();
```

Comment: OP is asking about basic C# concepts, not extension methods.